# Swap picture in slider plugin

Tags: plugins

I am a newbie with Wordpress and at the risk of sounding totally clueless, can I swap a picture out of a swiper/slider in html? I did not develop the site. I normally only work in html using Dreamweaver and was asked to do this quick change. I have uploaded the new picture to the correct folder, but I have not found the spot in the cpanel where I can edit the html portion.

```
(<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-314" src="https://weber-oil.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Spring-Into-Savings-March-1-April-30.png" alt="" srcset="https://weber-oil.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Spring-Into-Savings-March-1-April-30.png 611w, https://weber-oil.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Spring-Into-Savings-March-1-April-30-600x448.png 600w" sizes="(max-width: 611px) 100vw, 611px" width="611" height="456">
```

Comment: Such a spot may not exist, you'll need to contact the support provider for the theme or plugin that implements the slider, 3rd party dev support is offtopic here

Answer (score 0):

To change most things in WordPress, you do not edit HTML code directly. Usually there is an admin interface to make things simpler for end users. If you log into the wp-admin area of the site, there is likely either a plugin or a theme generating that end HTML, and they most likely have a way to swap images out. If you can look through the installed plugins and theme, and look at their documentation, most will explain where and how to make the change.